# Rerouting console output to Swing component

Tags: java, swing

How can I reroute the console output (i.e. `System.out.println("text")`) to display to a Swing component such as a textbox?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You cannot re route it rather you could set the text in some text component such as JTextArea/JTextPane/JEditorPane/JTextField (whatever)

Comment: Not sure what the 5 individuals find so confusing about this question. The question is very straight forward and has a relatively simple answer. See [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for one potential solution.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question about a common problem. Never should've been closed.

Answer (score 3):

To reroute the console output, you have to

1. create your own `PrintStream` - e.g. `public class YourPrintStream extends PrinterStream`.
2. override the `print(String s)` method and update the text of a JTextField or a JTextArea
3. Call `System.setOut(new YourPrintStream())`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JTextArea`

Example

```
        JTextArea field=new JTextArea();
        field.setText("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ...

for **Textbox** [REFER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

```
JTextField jTextField=new JTextField();
jTextField.setText("put your text here");
```

for **Label**

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText("put your text here");
```

for **Textarea**

```
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
text.setText(""put your text here");
```